# Создание массива без константного размера

Tags: c++, массивы

Всех приветствую. Пытаюсь получить изображение по сокету.

Появилась такая проблема:

Необходимо из массива для получения создать массив исключительно с изображением, без всякого мусора.

Пытался сделать такое:

```
while (ignored_error != boost::asio::error::eof) {

    boost::array<char, 10000> RECV_DATA; // изображение "с мусором"

    size_t ImageSize = image_recver.read_some(
        boost::asio::buffer(RECV_DATA), ignored_error);

    char complete[ImageSize]; // Должен быть массив без мусора, исключительно само изображение

    for (int i = 0; i < ImageSize; i++) {
        complete[i] = RECV_DATA[i]; // заполняем массив
    }

    cout << ImageSize << " : " << complete.size() << endl; // убеждаемся, что размер массива схож с размером полученного изображения 

}
```

Но получал такую ошибку:

> E0028 выражение должно иметь константное значение OpenCvTest  D:\C++
>   Projects\ImageRecvTest\ReceiveImage.cpp   33      значение переменная
>   "ImageSize" (объявлено в строке 30) невозможно использовать как
>   константу

Пробовал так:

```
    char *complete[] = new char[ImageSize];
```

Но и тут получал ошибку:

> E0520 для агрегатного объекта требуется инициализация с использованием
>   "{...}"

Что делать?

Comment: `char * complete = new char[ImageSize];`, `char *complete[]` объявляет массив указателей

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Используйте `vector`
    std::vector a(size);